# Apache cannot access folders in my home directory

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am getting this error

```
Warning: include(/home/me/some_folder): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/my_web.php on line 6
```

I have tried modifying permissions like this

```
chown apache /home/me/some_folder
chmod 755 /home/me/some_folder
```

I still cannot get in! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I am running an instance of linux with apache

Comment: Does apache runs as user "apache"? Its usually "www-data" or "nobody".

Comment: Does the apache user also have read permissions to the /home and /home/me folders?

Comment: I think so because ps aux | grep https gives me

Comment: `apache    1482  0.0  2.0 418740 12456 ?        S    22:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd`

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger Theres no need to.

Comment: @user3667450 Thats doesn't quite mean anything, the apache process will lower the user level for the PHP scripts.

Comment: @Havenard - I forgot about that. This is a linux file system

Comment: okay, so then how do I find the name of my user to grant permissions to?

Comment: Are you including `/home/me/some_folder` or `/home/me/some_folder/some_file.php`? Because `include` doesn't work with folders.

Comment: I am including a specific file within the folder, it holds my mysql login information (outside of the web root)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give access to all files in `/home/me/some_folder`

```
chown -R apache /home/me/some_folder
chmod -R 755 /home/me/some_folder
```

Comment: Be sure that the user that starts the web server is good. As Havenard specifed in comment of the question, it's usually `www-data` or `nobody`. You should edit your question with the operating system that you use. It could help.

Comment: what do you mean by 'good'? should I just grant permissions to 'nobody' and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by

```
chmod 755 /home/me/
```

I snuck around online a bit more and found an answer to a similar question on CentOS, and tried it

If someone could explain why, or security behind this, that would be greatly appreciated

Thanks for your help